# What is the closest equivalent to criminal compensation orders in other jurisdictions?

Tags: united-states, england-and-wales, any-jurisdiction, criminal-procedure, compensation

In the U.K., or at least in England, if Bob is convicted of a crime of which Alice is a victim, Bob may be ordered by the court at sentencing to pay to it on Alice’s behalf a sum representing losses and insults to Alice which she suffered as a result of Bob’s crime. This is known as a criminal compensation order.

I’d like to know how widely such mechanisms exist throughout the world, especially the U.S., but also for any jurisdictions that anyone would like to answer for.

Answer (score 1):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

In the United States, in criminal cases, this is known as a restitution order.

The measure of amounts awarded is narrower than in a civil action. The example of the Colorado law on the topic is discussed [here](https://www.shouselaw.com/co/defense/process/sentencing/victim-restitution/).

It is usually prepared, sometimes with a separate hearing, in parallel to the pre-sentencing and sentencing proceedings, following a conviction.

Answer (score 1):

[new-zealand](/questions/tagged/new-zealand)

This is called [sentence of reparation](https://www.legislation.govt.nz/act/public/2002/0009/latest/DLM135595.html).

Answer (score 1):

In [france](/questions/tagged/france) it is called *la peine de sanction-réparation*. (Rough translation: The sentence of the reparation penalty).

The relevant law is [article 131-8-1](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/codes/article_lc/LEGIARTI000006417244) of the *Code pénal*. It is also made applicable to non-individual persons (*personnes morales*) by [article 131-39-1](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/codes/article_lc/LEGIARTI000006417339).